# Rotating a polygon around it's center

Tags: c++, opengl, mathematics

I have drawn a ship using three lines, and would like to rotate the ship around its axis in opengl, I have tried the following, but the ship translates while rotation!.

```
void Ship::Draw( )
{
    gl::pushMatrices();
    gl::translate(Vec2f(-m_Pos.x, -m_Pos.y));
    gl::rotate(m_Angle);
    gl::translate(Vec2f(m_Pos.x,m_Pos.y));
    gl::color(ci::Color(1,0,0));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(281,70),Vec2f(383,123));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(310,85),Vec2f(310,160));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(383,123),Vec2f(281,176)); 

    gl::popMatrices();
    m_Angle+=0.2f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate a polygon around its centre like this, you need to draw it around the origin.

Currently you're drawing it off-centre:

```
gl::drawLine(Vec2f(281,70),Vec2f(383,123));
gl::drawLine(Vec2f(310,85),Vec2f(310,160));
gl::drawLine(Vec2f(383,123),Vec2f(281,176));
```

What this means is that these points are rotated around (0,0) by your angle `m_Angle`.

Instead, put equal amounts on either side of (0,0):

```
gl::drawLine(Vec2f(-43,-52),Vec2f(59,1));
gl::drawLine(Vec2f(-14,-31),Vec2f(-14,38));
gl::drawLine(Vec2f(59,1),Vec2f(-43,54));
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but the ship is drawn hidden and it is still rotating but translating also and not around the its center

Comment: I forgot to mention - you don't need to un-do the position translation. Remove `gl::translate(Vec2f(-m_Pos.x, -m_Pos.y));` as well.

Comment: it is worked. Could you explain more what was the problem ? and If I want to do the same scenario but with a circle or a rectangle what should I do ? 
What should I read more into ? OpenGL or 3D Math?

Comment: This answer is correct, but you better do a `glLoadIdentity()` after pushing the matrix, just in case there is any transformation accumulated before calling `Draw()`.

Comment: @Dan Would you explain it more ? I didn't get what I'm doing wrong. What should I read more ?

Comment: @MoazELdeen You should read documentation like [this](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm). When you do a `gl::pushMatrices()` you are saving the current state of the stack matrix, and through a `gl::popMatrices()` you will restore it as it was. Any transformation that you apply in between these two statements won't be kept outside them. Furthermore, if after pushing the current matrices you want to "reset" your transformations, you have to do a `gl::loadIdentity()`, do whatever you want to do, and then restore through `gl::pushMatrices()`.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, but why I wanted to shift the lines to negative points ?

Comment: You do this so the ship's centre is at (0,0). You turn the ship to the orientation you want first, and then move it to where you want it. Imagine you were using a drawing compass - if you set some length on it then rotating the compass around leaves a circle with the radius being the length. If your length was zero  then the pencil is equivalently on the spot.

Comment: @MattKemp Thanks, but how the numbers related to the center 0,0?

Comment: @MoazELdeen,  get a graph paper and draw a cross with 0,0 in center and roughly mark those points matt gave you on the graph. You will soon see why those negative numbers are there. Basically 0,0 is center and every point is relative to 0,0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any other `gl::translate` before that? What is the state of the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix at that time? Take into account that if you have accommulated other transformations then `gl::translate(-m_pos.x, -m_pos.y)` does not bring you back to the origin. I would call `glLoadIdentity()` rather then `gl::translate(-m_pos.x, -m_pos.y)`, then you rotate and translate where you want to go.